# I am struggling to get a game object to be destroyed when colliding with the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written code to heal the player after colliding with the health potion and then destroy the potion game object making it one time use, however, the gameobject does not get destroyed and the player is not healed. Code is as shown below:

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player" )
        {
            playerHealthScript.heal();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

(code below is in a seperate script, used for player health)

```
    public void heal()
    {
        currentHealth += healingAmount;
        currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth, 0, 100);

        healthBar.fillAmount = currentHealth / 100f;

    }
```

Comment: Is it 2d? Are you sure its tagged player? Does player gave rigidbody?

Answer (score 0):

Before seek for anything, you should Debug.Log("Collision") in your first function, maybe your code is right but the collision isn't detect.

If so, yo could consideer check if the syntax of "Player" is the same as the tag, or maybe your "Player" doesn't have any rigidbody2D ( 2D is important ! ).